# data calling from one page to another?

Tags: mysql, php

Hey guys i have a question. I am trying to set up something for my insurance website. I want to setup a capture page where the user inputs everything related to their vehicle and their information and once they click submit and proceed it directs them to another page of mine where it autopopulates all this information and gives them a quote. My question is how could i go about doing this?

Comment: What data do you want to store in the database and what steps have you taken to try to achieve what you want? There are hundreds of resources on the internet that show you how to store and retrieve data to/from mysql database with PHP.

Comment: XHR? Posting data to the next page and retrieving in the $_POST array? Plus, I really don't see where MySQL fits in if you will be going from one page to another directly.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution is to use a Form on one page, that'll be submitted to another page, where the data will be processed and populated.

you can find many examples on the internet.

here's a good example from PHP's DOCS - **[Dealing With Forms](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php)**:

HTML form:

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
 <p>Your name: <input type="text" name="name" /></p>
 <p>Your age: <input type="text" name="age" /></p>
 <p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

and action.php file, where the data will be handled:

```
Hi <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>.
You are <?php echo (int)$_POST['age']; ?> years old.
```

you can see that any information sent with a form via the POST method, can be captured in the target php file using the the $_POST variable (a [SuperGlobal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php)).